# Problema con xampp, php y html

Tags: php, html, xampp

Quiero realizar una pagina html, que tenga una base de datos (que almacene usuario/ email y contraseña.

La estoy creando con php y xampp pero a la hora de ejecutar el código me saltan errores a la hora de introducir nuevos usuarios en la base de datos.

el codigo es este en la registro de php:

```
<?php

  require 'database.php';

  $message = '';

  if (!empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['password'])) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (email, password) VALUES (:email, :password)";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(':email', $_POST['email']);
    $password = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
    $stmt->bindParam(':password', $password);
    if ($stmt->execute()) {
      $message = 'Cuenta creada correctamente.';
    } else {
      $message = 'Error al crear cuenta, intentelo de nuevo.';
    }
  }

?>
```

y tengo una pagina de database.php que el codgio es este

```
<?php
    $server = 'localhost'; //contiene el nombre de la base de datos
    $username = 'root';
    $password = '';
    $database = 'php_login_database';//este es el nombre de la tabla que cree en phpMyadmin
    try {//conectamos con la base de datos 
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$server;dbname=$database;", $username, $password);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {//muestra el error 
        die('Conexión fallida y finalizar el proyecto. ' . $e->getMessage());
    }
?>
```

y el error que me salta es al pulsar el botón de registar es objeto no localizado.

¿Alguien sabe cual puede ser el problema?

O alguien puede recomendar algún tutorial para crear una pagina de inicio de sesión que conecte con base de datos que tenga almacenados los usuarios y deje crear nuevos usuarios.
Muchas gracias a todos

Comment: Agrega el form que usas, pues parece que la ruta que invocas no es la indicada

Comment: Procura incluir en la pregunta, el mensaje de error completo (copia y pega el texto como texto, sin imágenes)

Answer (score 1):

Bienvenido a stackoverflow te recomiendo este vídeo, incluye descarga de el proyecto terminado en el que trabaja, te explica cada parte de el programa, y es muy llamativo, ya solo tendrias que conectar la base de datos. Yo lo utilice para la realización de un trabajo y necesitaba que fuera rapido :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lFTMdlr8coQ

Pero si deseas solucionarlo te recomiendo usar este metodo de conexicon envez de PDO que me parece mas facil:

```
<?php

$server = “localhost”;

$usuario = “root”;

$contraseña = “”;

$bd = “ejemplo”;

$conexion = mysqli_connect($server, $usuario, $contraseña, $bd) or die (“Se encontró un Error en la conexión favor de reportar”);

$insertar = “INSERT into datos('usuario','password') values (‘$usuario’,$password)”;

$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $insertar) or die (“Error al insertar los registros favor de reportar”);

Mysqli_close($conexion);

Echo “En hora buena los datos fueron insertados correctamente a nuestra base de datos”;
```

Comment: Responder con solo enlaces se considera de baja calidad, lee [answer]

Comment: "Los enlaces a recursos externos son aceptables pero no se te vaya a olvidar agregar el contexto alrededor de los enlaces. Esto ayudará a tus colegas a tener una idea de lo que son, y el porqué decidiste añadirlos."

Comment: Si ese enlace deja de funcionar la información se pierde, añade aquí lo relevante y solo déjalo como referencia, te recomiendo la edición pues por eso te han votado negativo

Comment: Te voté positivo sin embargo trata de formatear el código, seleccionándolo y presionando ctrl + k